# Encoding "two out of three" in clojure.core.logic

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I need to write some core.logic code that checks whether two out of three goals succeed.

I know I can write it like this:

```
(run* [a b c]
      (conde [goal1 goal2]
             [goal2 goal3]
             [goal3 goal1]))
```

...but this is cumbersome, and I actually need to generalize my code for the "N out of M" case, and this will be difficult to generalize. Can someone point me to the right approach to use for this type of problem? Is there a function available that simplifies this?

Thanks!

Comment: In Prolog, it's possible to do a "2 out of N" goals rule like this: `two_of(GS) :- append(XS, YS, GS), member(X, XS), YS = [Y|_], X, Y.` (This may not be valid standard Prolog, but it works in both SWI-Prolog and GNU Prolog.) But I cannot find a way to translate this into core.logic because it doesn't allow to treat variables as goals the way Prolog does here. (Error message is `ClassCastException clojure.core.logic.LVar cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`.) Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Thanks Rord for these insights... good to know my question is at least somewhat non-trivial to answer. (or bad, depending on how you look at it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a macro can help:

```
(defmacro n-of-m-goals [n all-goals]
   `(conde ~@(combinations all-goals n))
```

Then your example would become:

```
(run* [a b c]
      (n-of-m-goals 2 [goal1 goal2 goal3]))
```

combinations is from [math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics)

Comment: Wow, very elegant solutions- Thanks for sharing this!